# gem install rails : failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I try to install rails recently

but got these errors

I tried some similar solution but not working

the answers before had already are too old to me right now

so please have a look if you're free:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-
1.8.0/ext/nokogiri
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170908-68164-1pf24m0.rb 
extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-
argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.2.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
********************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4
with the following patches applied:
- 0001-Fix-comparison-with-root-node-in-xmlXPathCmpNodes.patch
- 0002-Fix-XPointer-paths-beginning-with-range-to.patch
- 0003-Disallow-namespace-nodes-in-XPointer-ranges.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
    [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
    [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
********************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-
darwin16.7.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running git apply with /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-
1.8.0/patches/libxml2/0001-Fix-comparison-with-root-node-in-
xmlXPathCmpNodes.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-
1.8.0/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-XPointer-paths-beginning-with-range-
to.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-
1.8.0/patches/libxml2/0003-Disallow-namespace-nodes-in-XPointer-
ranges.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review 
'/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-
1.8.0/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-
darwin16.7.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. 
Last lines are:
====================================================================
unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned 
short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
CC       error.lo
CC       parserInternals.lo
CC       parser.lo
CC       tree.lo
CC       hash.lo
CC       list.lo
CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                               ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
====================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of 
necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  
You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--help
--clean
--use-system-libraries
--enable-static
--disable-static
--with-zlib-dir
--without-zlib-dir
--with-zlib-include
--without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
--with-zlib-lib
--without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
--enable-cross-build
--disable-cross-build
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-
2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:400:in `block in execute': 
Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-
2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:371:in `chdir'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-
2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:371:in `execute'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-
2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:114:in `compile'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-
2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:153:in `cook'
from extconf.rb:365:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
from extconf.rb:364:in `block in process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log 
which can be found here:

/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-
16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-
darwin-16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.0/gem_make.out
```

ruby -v => ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]

git --version =>git version 2.14.1

Thanks all.

Comment: Install libxml2 packages. `brew install libxml2` Or install xcode `xcode-select --install and gem install nokogiri`.

Answer (score 0):

i've just experienced the same error, have you tried to run `ridk` from the command line? Is a tool that ships with Ruby and that let you install MSYS, which is necessary for Rails. Use `ridk install` and get both the Base installation and the dev toolchain, then retry to install Rails. It worked for me, hope this helps!